# How to refresh codemirror when it's parent div style becomes display block?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using codemirror with textareas in a tabbed interface, when i'm not in the tab that contains codemirror and then go to it, I get empty white space without line numbers or the cursor, when I refresh the page it works, I know it's because the tabs content is hidden using `display: none;` so how can I fix this issue ?

here's my code, (I'm also using jquery):

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById($this.attr('id')), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: text/html,
        enterMode: "keep",
        tabMode: "shift"
    });

    $(editor.getScrollerElement()).width(300);
    width = $(editor.getScrollerElement()).parent().width();
    $(editor.getScrollerElement()).width(width);
    editor.refresh();
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you also call `refresh` when switching to the tab that contains the editor.

Answer (score 15):

**Try this :**

```
// Refresh CodeMirror
$('.CodeMirror').each(function(i, el){
    el.CodeMirror.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`autorefresh`](https://codemirror.net/addon/display/autorefresh.js) addon:

> display/autorefresh.js
>
> This addon can be useful when initializing an editor in a hidden DOM
>   node, in cases where it is difficult to call refresh when the editor
>   becomes visible. It defines an option autoRefresh which you can set to
>   true to ensure that, if the editor wasn't visible on initialization,
>   it will be refreshed the first time it becomes visible. This is done
>   by polling every 250 milliseconds (you can pass a value like {delay:
>   500} as the option value to configure this). Note that this addon will
>   only refresh the editor once when it first becomes visible, and won't
>   take care of further restyling and resizing.

You just need to add JS library and set `autoRefresh` to `true`:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById($this.attr('id')), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: text/html,
    enterMode: "keep",
    tabMode: "shift",
    autoRefresh: true
});
```

Comment: And how can you add it?

Comment: @GáborCsikós save the js at folder `/addon/display/autorefresh.js` in your `CodeMirror` directory.

Comment: In case anyone wants more details on the autoRefresh option: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_autorefresh

Answer (score 0):

**select the class of '.CodeMirror' and instance the object for refresh when change size**

*For example in my case I want to click a button to add and remove an 'active' class to make the content of CodeMirror appear and disappear.*

```
.CodeMirror {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 10px 0 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}

.CodeMirror.active {
  display: block;
}
```

CodeMirror Object

```
const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea,{
    lineNumbers:true,
    tabSize:4,
    theme: 'material',
    mode:"javascript",
    readOnly: true,
  });
```

Event of btn

```
    btn.addEventListener('click', showCode)
```

**Solution**

```
function showCode () { 
  const editor= document.querySelector('.CodeMirror')
  editor.classList.toggle('active')
  
  // use the object for refresh CodeMirror 
  editor.CodeMirror.refresh()
}
```